# Error when fetching MSSQL database view data CakePHP 3

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have experience in using cakephp 2 but i have no idea in cakephp 3.

My database admin keep creating database table with uppercase name even in column name,
so i have to make cakephp model with custom table/view name.

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class ListCrewBooking extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('VW_CREW_ON_DUTY');
    }
}
```

and then i want to preview it on a controller directly without a cake view (using die();)

```
class TestController extends AppController
{
    function index(){

        $this->viewBuilder()->layout = false;
        $this->loadModel('ListCrewBooking');

        $data = $this->ListCrewBooking->find('all');
        pr($data);
        die();
    }
}
```

and then an error comes out

> **Cannot describe list_crew_booking. It has 0 columns.**

Why this is happened? and how to solve this?
i have no clue what is going on.

*ps: the view have 5000 rows and many columns*

Thank you for any reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently Cake 3 is not able to inspect views in the database when using the Sql server driver. There was a pull request for it, but was abandoned by the author. Maybe, if you have knowledge of this database, you can contribute this feature?